# NiFi Dynamically create requests for InvokeHTTP

Tags: apache-nifi

New to NiFi!

I have a scenario where I make one rest request and get some data back. The data I receive contains an ID which I need to make subsequent requests. So for example:

**InvokeHTTP GET** 
request:

1. http://localhost:2999/names

result:

```
[
    {
        id: 123
    },
    {
        id: 345
    }
]
```

**InvokeHTTP GET**
Request:

1. http://localhost:2999/id/**123**/rest/of/url
2. http://localhost:2999/id/**345**/rest/of/url

Is there a way for me to assemble the two requests above to pass to InvokeHTTP in NiFi?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the response is in JSON, you probably want to use [`SplitJson`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.2.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.SplitJson/index.html) to split the array into separate flowfiles, then use [`EvaluateJSONPath`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.2.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.EvaluateJsonPath/index.html) to extract the `id` values into flowfile *attributes* (one per flowfile). From there, you can feed those flowfiles into another [`InvokeHTTP`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.2.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.InvokeHTTP/index.html) processor and reference the relevant attribute values.

Comment: Thank-you! So, I'm at the point where i have extracted the ID, i'm just not too sure how the InvokeHTTP processor will reference it? Thanks again

Comment: In the *Remote URL* field of the processor, you can reference flowfile attributes via Expression Language like so: `https://example.com/${id}/some/path`.